# Sore Thighs After Workout

Tags: physique

I have been doing workout for over a month now. I also workout my thighs according to the routine. But in the last week my thighs muscles sore so much that i found it very hard to walk and to climb stairs especially. The condition remained same for 4 to 5 days. Now I m still feeling some sore in my thighs. My question is this is not the first time I trained my thighs so why did it happen so badly this time?

Comment: What thigh exercises do you normally do, and what did you do differently this time? (Note: Changes in weight or number of repetition do count as differences.)

Comment: A month is not really a long time. I think you just have to accept that at the beginning, when changing stuff or when training infrequently, this is going to happen from time to time. Why? Because you are not used to the stimulation. If you are wondering how doms happens, perhaps consider a google search or a search here. This has been explained in other threads

Comment: How long do you let your tights rest between two workouts ?

Comment: I am training my thighs only once in a week. I increased weights for the leg extension exercise this time. I do squats, pistol squats, leg press and hamstring exercises on thighs day

Comment: @user17948 Do your long term knee-health a favour and drop the leg extensions. They are an open chain movement, meaning that the foot is off the floor and all the force goes through the knee. This creates a shear force ie the shin and the thigh want to move in different directions, and the only thing stopping them is your cruciate ligament (ACL). Too much weight and SNAP! - here comes reconstructive surgery. This is the voice of experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no specific injuries caused by the training, you are suffering a combination of micro-tears in your muscle (this is good), and initially in the first day or so, a build up of lactic acid (sore - but no problem).

Why did this happen now and not previously? Perhaps you trained harder, squatted deeper, had less reset between sets or had your feet in a different position. Its impossible for me to know. But on with the mechanics of what has happened.

Muscle tears - this is an important phase of building muscle. You stress the muscle by performing resistance training to the point that your muscle actually micro-tears a little. Then, you recover and your muscle repairs the tears, with a little extra added in - so your muscle is now bigger and stronger. This is a slow process, and you need the recover time to grow the muscle, which is why people often train split routines, where the muscle group is only trained once per week.

Lactic acid - this is a byproduct of converting glucose into muscular energy. Due to the way the acid is formed, it can accumulate in the muscles quickly, but unfortunately it is harder to disperse, so you end up with soreness. It is very common and not a problem. In fact, it relates to the old, "No Pain, No Gain" saying, ie if you haven't trained hard enough to be sore, you haven't trained hard enough!

To save my description here, I would also recommend you look up "Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness" (DOMS).

To summarise, the soreness is normal, good even (possibly!) and something to expect on occasion if you train regularly. Just be careful not to overdo things and get injuries. Slow and steady is best when starting out, and never ego-lift if you want to avoid injuries!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons:

First of all, you could have worked out your thighs after a break or maybe you might have hit the muscle from different angles. For instance, little variation in exercises such as squats, leg extension and leg curls can work on your thighs from different angles.

Secondly, you might have increased weight or added some new exercise into your leg routine.

I don't think there's anything to worry about if the pain has subsided and you are OK now.